# Magento 1: Configurable products unable to find simple products in Associated

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, configurable-product, associate-products

So here is the Issue, Im trying to associate simple products to the configurable, now all products have been inputted, and are fine, for now in b2b store.
When I go to the configurable product only 24 show up after resetting filters, changing the filter to any and so on, nearly 1000 products are available but 976 do not show. any ideas from the group please? Cache and indexing are refreshed and so on. I look forward to your assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if those simple products has the same attribute set as configurable product. Also make sure all attributes marked in the configurable products as "configurable" are filled in simple product.