# Magento simple product

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created simple products and then I have create configurable product now when I am checking the associated product tab its showing blank, no products are visible.

Comment: Have you used any attribute to differentiate your products like size,color etc.

Comment: yes using coolor

Comment: did reindexing and cache management?

Comment: yess i did but showing in manufaturer attribute not in color

Answer (score 0):

please refer the link [Magento simple product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135119/magento-1-configurable-products-unable-to-find-simple-products-in-associated?rq=1).

I think your problem is because of this.